# how to create Google Chrome shortcut on desktop for CentOS

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos, shortcuts

I have successfully downloaded and installed Google Chrome from repository, and I can run it from a terminal.

My question is, how can I create a shortcut or a launcher on my desktop in CentOS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My friend **Xerath**. As all we know - whole Linux OS is a SDK and everything is a file. On such system - most of us like to be professionals. So here is more professional explanation how to put a shortcut in your desktop place:

```
1. Open terminal (xterm, konsole or whichever terminal you use)

2. Change the directory to your Desktop place:
```

`~$ cd ~/Desktop`

```
3. Use your favourite editor (for me it is vim) and type:
```

`~$ vim chrome-browser.desktop`

> 4. Put a content like this:
>      
>      `[Desktop Entry]
>      Comment[en_US]=This is my best browser
>      Comment=This is my best browser
>      Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome
>      GenericName[en_US]=Chrome
>      GenericName=Chrome
>      Icon=google-chrome
>      MimeType=
>      Name[en_US]=Google Chrome
>      Name=Google Chrome
>      Path=/tmp/
>      StartupNotify=true
>      Terminal=false
>      TerminalOptions=
>      Type=Application`
> 5. Save, give right permissions and... launch! Should work without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Following this [post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=47122) it seems you can:

```
 - Open the file browser 
   (the "home" folder shortcut is on the desktop by default)
 - Click the "Computer" link on the left navigation panel 
   and go to "/usr/shared/applications".
   This should display all the applications icons/shortcuts 
   in the browser window.
 - do "Right-click Icon->Context Menu->Copy To". 
   This will bring up another browser window titled "Select Destination".
 - Select (left-click) the "Desktop" folder in the left navigation panel, 
   and the click the "Select" button in the bottom right.
 - The Application icon should now be on the desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier solution would be:

Go to files:usr:share:applications:chrome

right click and then press copy to

then click desktop

it wont show up until you get tweak tool

press crtl+alt+t

then type sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool 
type in your password
then once it's downloaded go to desktop and click show applications on dektop
then chrome should be there!